# SQL query giving wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

When i run following query it shows only 1 row. Based on "created_date" condition, where as if i remove "created_date" condition and just keep "status_change_date" condition it shows 3 rows.

I want to see all items those were created or modified in specified time. I am unable to find whats wrong in the query

```
`SELECT DISTINCT products.id AS product, status.id AS stat, COUNT(*) AS total FROM items 
      INNER JOIN products ON (items.fk_product_id = products.id) 
      INNER JOIN status ON (items.fk_status = status.id) 
      WHERE DATE(items.status_change_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13' 
      OR DATE(items.created_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13' 
      AND status.id = 2 
      GROUP BY products.name, status.name order by products.name`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause looks wrong, try:

```
WHERE 
    (DATE(items.status_change_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13' 
    OR DATE(items.created_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13')
        AND status.id = 2 
        GROUP BY products.name, status.name order by products.name
```

Comment: when i take away status.id =2 to see for all statuses it shows 1 row again for status.id = 2 in whole result set

Comment: i removed DISTINCT still its same

Comment: @Johal Did you try putting parens around your where clause? There may be other things wrong with your query, but you were doing x OR y AND z instead of (x or y) and z. The way you had it written you would only return records if the change_date was within the date range OR if the created date was within date range and the status id was 2. I think you want to return records where the change date or the modified date are within the date range and the status id is 2.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling the conditions are being evalulated like this

```
status_change_date or (created_date and status.id = 2)
```

You might try using parentheses to designate the grouping of your conditions

```
( DATE(items.status_change_date)... OR DATE(items.created_date)... )
    AND status.id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Put brackets around your date clauses:

```
  WHERE (DATE(items.status_change_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13' 
  OR DATE(items.created_date) BETWEEN '2011-04-13' AND '2011-05-13')
  AND status.id = 2
```